# Constructor is "invoked" vs. Constructor is "executed"?

Tags: java, constructor, terminology

What is the difference betweeen constructor invocation and  constructor execution? 
I am reading about constructor order dependecies from java programming langauage by james Gosling.The author states that when you create an object  constructor is first invoked, then feild members are intialized finally costructor is executed.Both sounds the same to me.

Comment: I suspect that it means when you create an object, the **superclass** constructor is invoked, then field members are initialized, etc.  I don't think there was intended to be any significance behind using different terms--they mean the same thing.  But this is just a guess since I don't have the book.  If it's available online so that we can read the text ourselves, that might help.

Comment: When an object is created, java first needs to allocate memory space for that object to hold the variables.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that context, "invoked" is when *you* call it, and "executed" is when *the body of code is actually run*.

Between the time you call it and the time the code runs, the fields are initialized.

So, you *invoke* it, then initialization happens, *then* it is executed.

Try this:

```
class Example {

    static int report() { System.out.println("initialize"); return 0; }

    int x = report(); // <- [Step 2] Initialization

    Example () {
        System.out.println("execute"); // <- [Step 3] Execution
    }

}
```

Then, elsewhere:

```
System.out.println("invoke");
new Example(); // <- [Step 1] Invocation
```

The output will be:

```
invoke
initialize
execute
```

Comment: +1; actually, you can see this behaviour when you debug a class and set the break point in the constructor